# Do I need Git LFS for local repos?

Tags: git, git-lfs

I created a Git repo that will exclusively be stored locally and I ask myself, if I really need Git LFS for binaries? As far as I can see, the `.gitattributes` is properly configured as in:

```
*.psd binary
```

And yes, the files land in `.git/objects/...`, but they are compressed and don't take much space. So to sum it up, what are the benefits of Git LFS in a local repository if I never push/pull from/to a remote repo?

Thanks!

Comment: As far as I know, setting the `binary` attribute only affects the behavior of `git diff`. I don't think it affects the way the file is stored.

Comment: That makes sense! Thanks!

Comment: See also my Q: [How does git LFS track and store binary data more efficiently than git?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75946411/4561887), and this other Q: [What is the advantage of git lfs?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35575400/4561887).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## To git-lfs or not to git-lfs?

`git-lfs` stores old versions of file contents in the cloud while keeping their history on disk. This has two main benefits.

1. It can drastically reduce the size of the initial `git clone` of a repository.
2. It can drastically reduce the size of the local repository.

Obviously number 1 doesn't apply if the repository is never shared.

If these binaries are *really* large, and if you change them frequently, they may begin to impact your available free disk space. If so, git-lfs can be of benefit by offloading the old copies of the binaries to cloud storage.

Fortunately, you can always [retroactively apply git-lfs later using the BFG Repo Cleaner](https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/use-bfg-to-migrate-a-repo-to-git-lfs/) if the local repo gets too large.

## Binary or not?

> As far as I can see, the .gitattributes is properly configured as in: `*.psd binary`

This is a separate issue from `git-lfs`.

If the file is marked as binary, Git will assume it cannot usefully diff nor merge the contents. Every time you change the file Git will store a complete copy of the file. This will obviously eat up a lot more disk space.

Even if the file is "binary" (ie. not plain text), Git may be able to store only the change if you don't mark it as binary. However, if the file is already compressed this effectively randomizes the file contents and makes diffing impossible. Many image formats are compressed.

[Alexander Gogl did some experiments in their answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68623227/14660) and it seems Git will store the whole .psd file.

Comment: Thanks! Do you know why? If the file didn’t change, it should result in the same commit file sha, no?

Comment: @DanielStephens No, if a file does not change it will result in the same blob ID and the contents will not be duplicated. [The commit ID is made up of a bunch of things](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29107504/14660). See https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Git-Objects

Comment: Thanks! Can you elaborate your first sentence then? Just so i understand the differences. I will accept this then as an answer

Comment: @DanielStephens How's that?

Comment: Thanks! That pretty much answers my question. One last-side question though I am still trying to understand. What would be different with Git LFS? If Git "alone" stores the object as a compressed version, what does Git LFS add in value to this? The test-file I see in my Git LFS test repo is not even compressed as far as I can see

Comment: @DanielStephens Instead of storing the historic content of large files on disk, it stores them in cloud storage and fetches them on demand. Since you're making the commits locally, I think it will cache them. You'll probably have to manually purge the lfs cache.

Comment: I don't understand how this answer is considered correct. Not really answering the actual question "Do I need Git LFS for local repos?", it leans the reader towards to concluding "Yes, I need Git LFS", which is plainly the wrong answer. For repositories that are strictly local, having a local Git LFS server will result in a downgrade of performance (more disk space) than having just a local Git repository.

Comment: @JorgeGalvão I think the question changed subtly while I was writing the answer. I'll update.

Comment: You've identified 2 apparent "benefits" of `git lfs`: it reduces the size of the initial clone of a git repo, and it reduces the size of the local repository. But, I consider these two things to be _negatives_, because they come with a massive tradeoff: `git checkout` time. For 3 years I've worked in a large mono-repo where a single `git checkout` regularly takes **3+ hours** instead of a few seconds. That's the cost of the two "benefits" above. So, today, I strongly recommend _against_ using `git lfs`. [More details are in my question here.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75946411/4561887)

Answer (score 13):

It depends on your workflow and the facilities you have access to.

Git stores versions of files as blobs. These blobs are diff compressed, whereby only differences are stored. Therefore, the file size increases only marginally.

The situation is different if the versioned file is a binary or a file where a single change restructures the whole file. In that case, Git stores a copy of each file, whereby the repository grows rapidly.

#### Comparison between Git and Git-LFS blob sizes

Git does a good job in diff compressing even big files. I've found that the compression of large files can be excellent (size of versioned file in `.git/` after running `git commit` or `git gc`):

| type | change | file size | as git-lfs blob | as git blob | after git gc |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Vectorworks (.vwx) | added geometry | 28.8 MB | 28.8 MB | 26.5 MB | 1.8 MB |
| GeoPackage (.gpkg) | added geometry | 16.9 MB | 16.9 MB | 3.7 MB | 3.5 MB |
| Affinity Photo (.afphoto) | toggled layers | 85.8 MB | 85.6 MB | 85.6 MB | 0.8 MB |
| FormZ (.fmz) | added geometry | 66.3 MB | 66.3 MB | 66.3 MB | 66.3 MB |
| Photoshop (.psd) | toggled layers | 25.8 MB | 25.8 MB | 15.8 MB | 15.4 MB |
| Movie (mp4) | trimmed | 13.1 MB | 13.1 MB | 13.2 MB | 0 MB |
| delete a file |  | -13.1 MB | 0 MB | 0 MB | 0 MB |

If **you don't have** a remote to push to, it is better to not use Git-LFS because Git-LFS versioned files seem to add no additional compression at all (see above).

Also one important lesson learnt here is that Git's diff compression method doesn't work with real binary files like .fmz. These would be the best candidates for putting under Git-LFS versioning.

For other file types that seem to be non-textual, but their structure is text-like (.vwx or .afphoto) the diff method performs well. In a single user scenario, where overall repository size and not committing speed is critical, I wouldn't put these under Git-LFS versioning because the Git blob size is significantly smaller than the LFS blob, thus saving space at the local and the remote.

#### Benefits of Git-LFS

Git-LFS provides a solution to this problem by storing older version of large binary files at a place **outside the repository** (the Remote) and replacing it by a pointer file. If an older version is needed, then the client pulls it from the remote. Therefore, if a designer pulls the latest state from the remote, he will only download the latest state and the pointer files.

Therefore, Git-LFS can only be facilitated if you have access to a remote that is located at an LFS-enabled server. If there is no server to push the blobs to, then LFS-tracked blobs will stay in the local repo, therefore the advantage of decreasing local storage consumption is not utilized.

Usually, the remote is an LFS-enabled git provider, which can be too expensive for some projects. However, there are also solutions to host a Git-LFS remote locally.

#### How to integrate Git-LFS in a local repository

Natively, Git-LFS allows transferring data through HTTPs only. Therefore, you require a separate Git-LFS server for storing the large files. However, there is ''no official server'' [implementation](https://github.com/sinbad/lfs-folderstore) for local hosting. But there are some [unofficial](https://github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/wiki/Implementations) ways like [Git-LFS Folderstore](https://github.com/sinbad/lfs-folderstore) to do that.

**Git-LFS Folderstore** provides a way to manage a Git-LFS remote locally. It works on a local machine and on a network drive. If you are on Mac OS X, then you can set it up by copying the lfs-folderstore executable `lfs-folderstore` to `/usr/local/bin` and then:

```bash
# Creating a remote repository on a volume (attached drive or NAS)
cd path/to/remote
mkdir origin

# create a bare git repository in origin
cd origin
git init origin --bare

# Add remote to local repository
cd path/to/local/repository
git remote add origin <path/to/remote/origin>

# Enable Git-LFS in local repository
git lfs install

# Track filetype psd
git lfs track "*.psd"

# Configure lfs of the local repository
git config --add lfs.customtransfer.lfs-folder.path lfs-folderstore
git config --add lfs.standalonetransferagent lfs-folder
git config --add lfs.customtransfer.lfs-folder.args "Volumes/path/to/remote/origin"

# Commit changes
git commit -am "commit message"

# Push media to remote
`git push origin master`
```

Use `"'` if your remote path contains spaces.

#### How to cleanup the local repository

You can compress the size of your git repository by calling the Git Garbage Collector `git gc`. It won't touch the Git-LFS blobs tough.

Git-LFS will only remove blobs from the local repository `.git/lfs/objects/` if they have been pushed to a remote AND if the commit containing the blobs is older than recent (3 days). Here are the commands if you want to do it manually:

```bash
# remove lfs duplicates
# https://github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/blob/main/docs/man/git-lfs-dedup.1.ronn
git lfs dedup

# clean old local lfs files (>3 days of commit)
# https://github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/blob/main/docs/man/git-lfs-prune.1.ronn
git lfs prune
```

Comment: Excellent answer! It's not super clear from your answer, but I think you're saying if you add a 28.8 MB file, it's 26.5 MB as a git blob, and then drops to being only 1.8 MB after running `git gc` garbage collection, right?--as opposed to `git lfs`'s 26.5 MB blob that always remains 26.5 MB. From just reading the table alone, one might think that running `git gc` adds an additional 1.8 MB on top of the already-there 26.5 MB git blob. Please clarify.

Comment: Yes, `git gc` kompresses it, while `git lfs` leaves it as it is. The only advantage of git lfs is, that it will move older blobs from your local repository to a remote one, while the default git keeps everything local and on the remote.

Comment: Got it! Thanks for the reply. And I consider that one advantage to be generally [not an advantage at all](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76567696/4561887).

Comment: It can be an advantage in situations like mine, where you are working on a notebook that is attached to a network storage. In that case, you can save valuable local storage by pushing the file history of certain file types that are large to a network drive. That workflow builds up on the assumption that storage space is cheap, but time (reconstructing a lost version) is expensive.

Answer (score 3):

To add to the excellent answer already provided by @Schwern and address OP's comment.

Here is a [link](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/git-lfs) to the documentation of GIT LFS from Atlassian, one of the two main companies (the other is GitHub) which stand behind this extension.

The idea is that the binaries are downloaded from the "remote" repository **lazily**, namely during the checkout process rather than during cloning or fetching.

Technically  git lfs stores "lazily" evaluated pointers to the binaries.

This makes a lot of sense because git has a "commitment" to be able to provide you an access to the state of the code-base after each and every commit, so the following situation is possible:

1. commit A: added large binary file a.bin (lets say a.bin is in version 1)
2. push the changes
3. commit B: made changes in the binary file a.bin (a.bin is in version 2 now)
4. push the changes
5. Now checkout the SHA1 of the commit A - the git has to provide you a.bin in version 1.

This is true even if you've decided to remove the a.bin and commit it, there should still be a possibility to access the file-system state after "commit A".
So At least locally there is no point to store version 1 if you explicitly don't need that.

One more note, to directly address the question and clarify: yes you have to enable git lfs support locally, but in addition you also have to enable git lfs support on your remote repo (I did that with Bitbucket once, I'm sure its competitors support that as well).

Comment: Thank you! That is an excellent addition! But to me it seems Git LFS is only essential and beneficial if remote repos are involved, is that correct? If the repo never leaves the machine, it's not as beneficial, correct?

Comment: Well, yes, I guess so, although I've never seen that someone uses git lfs only locally...

Comment: "...the binaries are downloaded from the "remote" repository lazily, namely during the checkout process rather than during cloning or fetching". You just nailed the reason why `git lfs` is horrible to work with on large repos: [`git checkout` has regularly taken me 3+ hours instead of a handful of seconds for the last 3.5 years](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75946411/4561887).