# What is the advantage of DVC, git-annex, git-lfs for large or binary files over git?

Tags: git, git-lfs, dvc, git-annex

If I have different versions of a file, e.g., in different branches, and I try to reconcile those, git will has great mechanisms for that. However, in order to do the reconciliations, e.g., in a merge, git requires access to the "inside" of the file. Thus files should be text files.

If I change a version controlled file, git does not save the delta between those files, but safes and entire snapshot of the file. If one makes a change, even a small change, to a large file, the entire files will be stored twice by git. Thus files should be small.

Files that are either large or binary (or both), they should not be tracked by Git. If I still need them in my project, I should use something like DVC, git-annex, git-lfs.

As far as I understand, all three of those keep the those other files outside of git, and keep a reference, which is tracked by git. I will use DVC as a stand-in, as I know even less about the other two.

1. In DVC, the reference is a text file and thus, git will not get confused. However, since it is only a reference, there is not much merging to be done by git anyways. So, git's reconciliation-capabilities are not really required. What is the advantage of using DVC then regarding this aspect? Can't I just use git and just not use those mechanisms?
2. In DVC, it seems that if I change a large file, just like in git, a snapshot of that file is created (not a delta saved). So, how does this improve the situation compared to git? I still get lots of (near) copies of this big file.

I understand from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35578715/4533188) that git-lfs keeps most of the (near) copies of my file in the remote storage. Only if I checkout the respective version of the large file, the files is downloaded. In that case, while I would be correct about my point 2, at least it is only a "problem" of the server (in terms of space), but not on my local disk space and also not for the internet bandwidth usage. This might be the same for DVC.

Are my "objections" or "caveats" of the points 1 and 2 valid?

Comment: 1. Not exactly true, you still leverage all of Git features on DVC (in fact getting on Gitflow is one of the points of data version control in the first place), even merging: https://dvc.org/doc/user-guide/how-to/merge-conflicts

Comment: @JorgeOrpinelPérez: Are you sure? Yes, the reference is under git and we leverage git's branching, as you say. Also we are using git's ability to have different versions of a file (either in the same or other branches). But branching is not an issue for binary files either. The situation where a binary file becomes problematic is when we have a two different version of the same file on two different branches, such that the neither originates from the other, but both have a common ancestor. In other words, both have been changed in different places on different branches, independently.

Comment: When we then merge the branches, git needs to figure out, what to keep from which file, what the resulting file is. It can do that only if it can look inside those files. That is not possible for binary files. However, the DVC reference file is (although a text file) only containing stuff like a md5 hash, the name of the file and so on. There will not be a situation where we have a common ancestor and stuff changed at different places on different branches. At least, I do not see how that situation would occur.

Comment: Let's go through the stuff in the link you posted: `dvc.yaml` is not about version control in the context of this question, but about files that define process DAGs. They can be considered "normal source" code. DVC can do more than version control and this is one of those things, but my question is only about version control. `dvc.lock` is also not about that and, as they write, we should just pick one of the files and make no introspection.

Comment: `.dvc files - Simple tracking (add)` is a bit tricky, but if you look closely, you see: Either you do not merge (with introspection) and just pick reference (and referred-to-file) over the other, or you follow their process and merge (referred-to) directories manually (!) and then pick one reference over the other. `.dvc files - Append-only directories` - here I am indeed not a 100% certain what happens with the references. `Imported data` here I am not sure either, but this case might actually something were true introspection *does* happen.

Comment: Yep, there's no way to auto-merge arbitrary binary files because their format is only known to you as the user. Maybe some tools exist for specific formats but that's not something any of these versioned solutions will provide.

Comment: @JorgeOrpinelPérez: I am not trying to solve the question of merging binary files. I am just trying to understand what the advantage of the strategy (in the context of the question) of DVC (and similar) is compared to git.

Comment: Gotcha. In the case of DVC I recommend this article: https://dvc.org/doc/use-cases/versioning-data-and-model-files

Answer (score 0):

It's more of a need than just an advantage.

- Git is not meant to handle binary files in the first place, as their contents are not necessarily incremental (as with text/code) so no "delta saving" either.
- While Git can technically handle arbitrarily large files, it will be very slow in indexing them.
- Git hosting services like Github do have file size limits (even with LFS).

DVC in particular is nice because you don't need special servers to use it, just configure any storage provider you already own (e.g. some SSH box or an S3 bucket).

Re 2. DVC also makes sure no files are duplicated in your storage based on their content (great for datasets organized as multiple small files in a directory structure, [more info](https://dvc.org/doc/user-guide/large-dataset-optimization)).