# Comparison between Git LFS and simple Git

Tags: git, git-lfs

I have some questions:

- What are advantages of using Git LFS over simple Git for storing large files in repo?
- What is the maximum size of file that Git LFS can store upto?
- What are the cons of using Git LFS?

Comment: I feel like most of this is answered here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35575400/what-is-the-advantage-of-git-lfs

Comment: One relevant drawback is that since you no longer have the complete history locally you can run into situations where you can't check out an old commit fully while you're offline. Given the always-connected nature of most software development, I suspect that this rarely comes up, but it's something to keep in mind.

Comment: Note that if and when you do use Git-LFS, Git itself is *not aware of this*. The LFS wrappers hide the "large" files from Git, replacing them with "pointer files". I put "large" in quotes because these files need not actually be particularly large, though that's usually the reason for storing such files on a separate LFS server.