# files version control 'without push'

Tags: git, version-control

Is there a way to version control (large) files, by keeping them locally? (my 'local', is actually  on cloud)

(and show for instance on Github/lab only the commits -- like, by keeping only the checksums of all versions?)

Thanks

Comment: I think you're looking for [LFS](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35575400/184546).

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve? If you have a repository but all of the "real files" are only local for you, then what good is that repository? If your local copy gets lost somehow, the remote repository will be pointless, as the "real files" will be missing. Can you explain the underlying issue that you're trying to solve? I think this is a [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info).

Comment: I understand the industrial-strength way to do this while keeping complete control of your content is [`git annex`](https://git-annex.branchable.com/).

Comment: @TTT I tried LFS, but as it's says in the landing page: "...while storing the file contents on a remote server like GitHub.com or GitHub Enterprise." , so I don't think it's what I want

Comment: @JoachimSauer sorry, I wasn’t super clear: I actually wanna do VC of data on cloud. I don't wanna have a 100-GB repo on GH, of course (let's assume data on cloud is safe). 
So, actually having just a git repo where the data are, without remote can do the job, 'locally'. 
I was just wondering if there is a more elegant / advanced solution, that allows to have a copy of the commit history on e.g. GH/GL

Comment: Git Annex looks promising. Git-lfs kinda does something similar, but with most git hosting providers, it means you'll be storing the binaries in *their* cloud storage. But not directly in the git repo.

Answer (score 0):

This wouldn't version control the content of the files, but you could have symlinks to files in your repo and the actual files outside of the repo (For Windows see [core.symlinks](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-coresymlinks)).